# Access denied on TimeMachine after formatting OSX

Tags: macos, time-machine, permission

I formatted a Mac and installed the latest OSX. This Mac was using Time Machine with an external hard drive.

Now, I am unable to access folders on that disc that were created before the formatting.

In Finder they appear with a red stop icon and trying to open these folders give me an access denied error.

Trying to `chmod` or `chown` them gives me an error as well (with `sudo` obviously).

Here is what `ls` says about one of those folders:

```
drwx------+ 11 502  staff  -        816 20 aoû 19:11 Dropbox
0: group:everyone deny     add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown
```

I've also tried:
`sudo chflags -R nouchg Dropbox/`, it did not give any errors but did not fix anything.

Also:

```
sudo chmod -N Dropbox/ 
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file Dropbox/: Invalid argument
```

Comment: I'm confused as to how you restored toe Mac. Can you give more details on the restore process you used?

Comment: I accessed the Recovery tools during the booting, erased disk and re-installed OSX. I then upgraded to Yosemite (before doing anything else).

Comment: Ok so why is there a Dropbox folder you can't open? When Dropbox creates it, it has the right permissions. Did you use a different method to install Dropbox?

Comment: This folder was just an example, there are hundreds of folders. And again, this was working before the format. So sure permissions were fine.

Comment: Hmmm ok. That's very weird folders get their permissions get changed. Try this: [http://www.macissues.com/2014/04/11/how-to-fix-home-folder-permissions-in-os-x/](http://www.macissues.com/2014/04/11/how-to-fix-home-folder-permissions-in-os-x/).